# Installing third-party SSL certificate on oVirt hosts

Tags: ssl-certificate, rhel8, ssl-certificate-errors, ovirt

I am attempting to change the SSL certificates in use for my oVirt environment from the default self-signed certificates to third-party certificates. The process is well documented for performing this task on the ovirt-engine management server and I was able to perform this change without any issues. However, there is no official documentation regarding this process for host servers, and the only documented process for doing so I was able to find on GitHub [here](https://gist.github.com/qrkourier/9c9ac3e8b190dcb91d3767179d5a39ea). The instructions provided appeared to work at first but I got continuous VDSM "ERROR ssl handshake: SSLError, address: ::1" status messages when using "systemctl status vdsmd.service". Additionally, the host server fails to communicate with the ovirt-engine causing it to be unresponsive to any management commands run from the oVirt management console. I verified that my certificate files are all valid and placed in the correct locations and I ran a test openssl connection to the loopback address and got a successful handshake so I do not know where the issue is.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this SSL error or has anyone performed this procedure and got it to work?